# How to get table names in snake case with Quarkus and Panache

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have Java entities with a composite camel case name, e.g., `EmployeeProject`.

I need to map those entities on tables with snake case names, e.g., `employee_project`, instead of the default used by Quarkus/Panache, e.g., `employeeproject`.

I know I can set a custom table name with `@Entity(name = "employee_project")` but I was wondering if there is some sort of application property which do the same work for me.

Comment: You should set `@Table(name = "employee_project")`, not `@Entity(name = "employee_project")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom naming strategy for this purpose. Also see the following article which has an example for this very use case: https://thorben-janssen.com/naming-strategies-in-hibernate-5/#Names_in_snake_case_instead_of_camel_case

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate copied the [CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy.html) from Spring.

Just use it like this, without defining it again.

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.physical-naming-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Christian's answer and implementing a SnakeCaseNamingStrategy ([see here](https://thorben-janssen.com/naming-strategies-in-hibernate-5/#Names_in_snake_case_instead_of_camel_case)), you can use application.properties to configure it in Quarkus. This way you don't have to go through the configuring hibernate in persistence.xml.

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.physical-naming-strategy=com.example.SnakeCaseNamingStrategy
```